# Html form cannot pass to php

Tags: php, html, forms

passing-var.php

```
`<form method="post" action="catching-var.php">
 <input type="text" name="name1"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="name2"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="name3"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="name4"/><br/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
  </form>`
```

catching-var.php

```
<?php 
 $name0 = $_POST['name0'];
 $name1 = $_POST['name1']; 
 $name2 = $_POST['name2']; 
 $name3 = $_POST['name3']; 
 $name4 = $_POST['name4'];

 echo $name0.'<br/><br/>'; 
 echo $name1.'<br/><br/>'; 
 echo $name2.'<br/><br/>'; 
 echo $name3.'<br/><br/>'; 
 echo $name3.'<br/><br/>';
 ?>
```

I have search for most of the websites about html form passing variable through php variable.. I do not understand why my form from passing-var.php cannot pass the variable to catching-var.php..
I have check the codes for several times and still can't find out what is the problem..
Helps will be appreciated.. Thank You.. 
PS: I am very new to php and in the learning stage

Comment: what error are you getting? If this is your complete code it is probably because you don't have an input called `name0`

Comment: What does print_r($GLOBALS) tell you?

Comment: Maybe your `catching-var.php` action is not working because it's a relative path

Comment: Might be $_POST['name0'] isn't set... what's the error?

Comment: @MattBusche It just shows me the $echo $echo ?> at the catching-var.php page after i enter the value from the passing-var.php..
It does not shows the input that I have enter from passing-var.php..

Comment: @KevinCarmody the above comment is the error..
What do you mean by $_post['name0'] isnt set..
Sorry I am still a beginner in php...

Comment: If your generated page is showing unparsed php, you either don't have php set up right or some sort of syntax error that is tripping up php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that a POST variable is set before you try to use it. So as you haven't included  in your form, you're going to get an error when you try to access it. You can check if a var has been set

```
$name0 = (isset($_POST['name0']) ? $_POST['name0'] : 'not set');
```

Comment: hi Kevin now the catching-var.php has display me the "not set" statement.. So what should I do in order to get it set..

Comment: @user2089532 post something. Include something like `<input name="name0" value="foobar" />` in your hml

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't exist in your form:

```
$name0 = $_POST['name0'];
```

it would probably that say $name0 is not set. but the other name variable should work fine.

in your catching-var.php try doing this.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $name1 = $_POST['name1']; 
 $name2 = $_POST['name2']; 
 $name3 = $_POST['name3']; 
 $name4 = $_POST['name4'];

 echo $name1.'<br/><br/>'; 
 echo $name2.'<br/><br/>'; 
 echo $name3.'<br/><br/>'; 
 echo $name3.'<br/><br/>';

}
```

also make sure your files are in the same directory.